# if foreach and condition

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

please help me to solve this case,

dear.all.

ref:
foreach ($getvalue as $isi){if ($isi->eventHour == "00.01-00.30" is a data from database

$clock_now == clock now

$sdate = choice day

$today = today

this is my script checkbox disable

```
 <?php 
 foreach ($getvalue as $isi){
 if ($isi->eventHour == "00.01-00.30" or $clock_now >= "00.02" and $sdate == $today)
 echo 'disabled';
 }
 ?>
```

if foreach have a value/true then, this script output is echo disable

but when foreach not have value/false then this script output is not display echo disable

the question is

how to display echo 'disabled' where foreach not have a value?

so `or $clock_now >= "00.02" and $sdate == $today` is work and display echo disabled

thanks a lot

sory for my bad english

Best regard

Puja

Comment: Puja, unfortunately it's still hard to understand it. Can you make it a bit more understandable?

Comment: just check `false` or `empty` ? whats complication on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your english is pretty bad :)

As your question is not very clear I just hope what you want is maybe the `is_null()` or `isset()`.

```
if(is_null($isi->eventHour))
{
//do your work here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 

 $status = "disabled";  

 foreach ($getvalue as $isi){

    $status = "";

    if ($isi->eventHour == "00.01-00.30" or $clock_now >= "00.02" and $sdate == $today)
    {
       $status = "disabled";
    }
 }

 echo $status;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($getvalue as $isi){
    $eh = explode('-',$isi->eventHour);
    foreach($eh as $k=>$e)
        $eh[$k] = abs(trim($e));

    if(!is_numeric($eh[1])) $eh[1] = $eh[0];
    if ( ($clock_now >= $eh[0] && $clock_now<=$eh[1] && $sdate == $today) || empty($isi->eventHour))
        echo 'disabled';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to determine if the value is empty or not if it empty you execute the one if statement if not execute another

```
<?php 
 foreach ($getvalue as $isi){

if (empty($isi->eventHour)) {

    echo 'disabled';

}
if(!empty($isi->eventHour))
{
   if ($isi->eventHour == "00.01-00.30" or $clock_now >= "00.02" and $sdate == $today)
   echo 'disabled';
}
 }
?>
```